# What type of drawn sample is more informative about $\theta$?

Tags: inference

We have two sampling methods:
 1. $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ from a Bernoulli$(\theta)$ distribution;
 2. $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ from a Geom($\theta$) distribution.

Which is more informative about $\theta$ and also what would you choose if the sample size $n$ is large enough?

I'mnot sure what to say. 
The MLE in both cases is $\bar{X}$.
The UMVUE in both cases is also $\bar{Y}$.
Now I'm not sure what to look at.

The Variance of $\bar{X}$ is $\frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n}$
and the variance of $\bar{Y}$ is $\frac{1-\theta}{n\theta^2}$.

The Fisher information of $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$ is $\frac{n}{\theta(1-\theta)}$
and the fisher information of $(Y_i)_{i=1}^n$ is $\frac{n(1-\theta-\theta^2)}{\theta^2(\theta-1)}$.

What I've observed is that the MLE of the bernoulli sample achieves the cramer rao lower bound for the variance, but this is not true for the geometric case. Also the variance for the Bernoulli distribution is always less than the Geometric's.
Not sure what else to say.

Comment: Did you calculate the variance of $\bar{X}$ in both cases? Or the Fisher information?

Comment: Yep just edited in.